# Child class showing unknown behavior during inheritance

Tags: c++

I am making a simple program in which I created an abstract class of shape and rectangle class is inheriting from shape class.
My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class shape {
protected:
    int height;
    int width;
public:
    shape(int h, int w): height(h), width(w)
    {};
    virtual double area() = 0;
};
class rectangle: public shape {
public:
    rectangle(int h, int w): shape(height, width)
    {};
    double area() {
        return (height * width);
    }

};

int main() {
    rectangle r1(4, 8);
    cout << "Area of rectangle r1 is " << r1.area() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Area of rectangle r1 is 0
```

It is showing the area is 0 but it should've shown the area is 32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your constructor:

```
rectangle(int h, int w): shape(height, width) {};
```

instead of using the arguments `h` and `w`, you are using the existing values of `height` and `width`. Since these are not initialized, using them invokes undefined behavior, and you happen to see a result of 0.

If you turn on your warnings, the compiler should complain about this.

You need to do:

```
rectangle(int h, int w): shape(h, w) {};
```

Comment: is it necessary to inherit it this way? why can't I do it like defining the variables as height = h; and width = w; in the rectangle's constructor body?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But this is a better option since the `shape` constructor already has code that does what you want, so you can just use that.

Comment: if I'm defining it inside the constructor's body of rectangle it's showing error: no matching function for call to ‘shape::shape()’

Comment: Yes, because you don't have a default constructor for `shape`, it *must* be constructed with 2 arguments.